# How to trigger a button when an item from listview is seleted?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button

I have created a Windows Forms application with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I have a `listview1` which lists only the names of people from a Microsoft Access Database table which I have created, which works fine. I also have a button called `Search`.

What I want is to trigger this `Search` button whenever I click on a name from my `listview1`

An example with sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call search function/or search button event handler on list change event

Comment: private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SearchBox.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
                SearchButton.PerformClick();           
        }

Comment: Tip. Write a DoSearch Method, call that from the buttonclick event handler and listView1_Click. Having one eventhandler call another one, is a maintenance nightmare.